# QML: How to use a dynamically created component with a customized internal object?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I'm looking for a way to dynamically create a component and object, and use the *component*. It seems like most of the examples available, such as those in the Qt documentation or other StackOverflow posts, are related to using the object returned from createObject(), whereas I want to use the component which contains the (customized) object.

I've stripped out a lot of extraneous detail (e.g. the CustomContainer gets pushed onto/popped off of StackViews), but the following code hopefully illustrates what I'm trying to do... Basically, I would like to have the CustomControl rectangle with foo = 10 and bar = 10, but it seems to load with the defaults instead. There will be multiple "custom control" types and multiple "custom container" objects so I need to be able to support this generically.

The Qt documentation talks about [creation contexts](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html#maintaining-dynamically-created-objects), which I assume is my problem, but I'm not sure how to fix this. I'd prefer a purely QML solution, but C++ is fine if that's where the solution lies.

Main.qml:

```
CustomContainer {
    id: myCustomContainer
}

CustomContainer {
    id: myOtherCustomContainer
}

function addCustomControl( control, args ) {
    var newComponent = Qt.createComponent( control )
    var newObj = newComponent.createObject( myCustomContainer, args )
    return newComponent
}

myCustomContainer.loaderSource = addCustomControl( "CustomControl.qml", { "foo": 10, "bar": 10 } )

myOtherCustomContainer.loaderSource = addCustomControl( "CustomControl.qml", { "foo": 20, "bar": 20 } )
```

CustomControl.qml:

```
Rectangle {
    property int foo: 5
    property int bar: 5
}
```

CustomContainer.qml:

```
Item {
    property Component loaderSource

    onLoaderSourceChanged: {
        myLoader.sourceComponent = loaderSource
    }

    Loader {
        id: myLoader

        onSourceComponentChanged: {
            doStuff()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Component` != `object`. Moreover you are mixing static creation of objects (`Loader`) with dynamic creation (`createObject`) which could be fine but not like that. Either 1) use `Loader` and set the values in `onLoaded` or just use dynamic objects and that's it.

Comment: "...which could be fine but not like that" - could you expand on this? What would be the right way to do this? My problem is that I have a StackView which covers a large area, and I want to have different elements that are various sizes and positions within this area. Instead of resizing and re-positioning the StackView every time, I thought this solution made sense - use a container item that fills the StackView, then allow the internal object to be the size and position that it needs to be.

Comment: @ddriven answer pretty much describes the problem: mixing is possible but not directly since `Loader` uses `Component`s not `object`s. You can surely put a `Component` in a `Loader` and instantiate an `object` inside the `Loader` item (a correct way of mixing the approaches). In any case you are  adding complexity to something which should be used to simplify your code. In general, just use one or the other.

Answer (score 2):

The component does not "contain the object". The component is a prototype for objects to be instantiated. Think of it like a "type" or a `class` or `struct` in C++ vs an instance of that type.

Your code creates the component, and then creates an object from it with modified values for the properties, but the component still has its default properties, so using it as a source component will produce objects with default properties.

Furthermore, a `Loader` will do automatic dynamic instantiation for you. So you don't need to combine both manual and automatic, either do it manually, or leave the loader to do it.

Last, but not least, when components are instantiated by a `StackView` they will automatically fill it and their size will be bound to it, so it will automatically change as the `StackView` size changes. So just use an `Item` and put your content in there and layout it. Only the root item's size will be bound to the `StackView` size, its children items will have their own sizes.

Comment: That makes sense. RE: the last point, that's why I made a CustomContainer - it's supposed to be a root (full StackView size) Item that contains the content as a child (whatever size it wants to be). Do you have a suggestion for solving my problem within these constraints?